# Why photon room properties not found in lobby?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, photon

The player can create a room with certain properties that once created I set them and for lobby so that I can then display them in the lobby.

Function to create room:

```
   public void OnCreateRoomButtonClicked()
    {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.IsOpen = true;
        roomOptions.IsVisible = true;
        string roomName;
        string gameMap;
        if (gameMode.Equals("CarMeeting"))
        {
            gameMap = carMeetingModeMaps[mapIndex].sceneName;
            roomName = roomNameCarMeetingModeInputField.text;
            roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            gameMap = racingModeMaps[mapIndex].sceneName;
            roomName = roomNameRacingModeInputField.text;
            roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 2;
        }

        if (!CheckIfRoomAlreadyExists(roomName))
        {
            StartCoroutine(EShowWarning());
        }
        else
        {
            roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties = new Hashtable();
            roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties.Add("GameMap", gameMap);
            roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties.Add("GameMode", gameMode);
            roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties.Add("RaceMode", raceMode);
            roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties.Add("InRace", false);

            string[] customLobbyProperties = new string[4];
            customLobbyProperties[0] = "GameMap";
            customLobbyProperties[1] = "GameMode";
            customLobbyProperties[2] = "RaceMode";
            customLobbyProperties[3] = "InRace";

            roomOptions.CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = customLobbyProperties;

            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions, null, null);
        }
    }
```

Function display rooms in lobby:

```
  public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log("Rooms found " + roomInfo.Count);
        bool roomFound = false;

        foreach (RoomInfo room in roomInfo)
        {
            if (room.RemovedFromList)
            {
                int index = roomUIs.FindIndex(x => x.roomNameString.Equals(room.Name));

                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Destroy(roomUIs[index].gameObject);
                    roomUIs.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CMRoomUI cacheRoomUI = roomUIs.Find(x => x.roomNameString.Equals(room.Name));
                if (cacheRoomUI != null)
                {
                    if (room.CustomProperties["GameMode"].ToString().Equals("CarMeeting"))
                        cacheRoomUI.Check(room.Name, (room.PlayerCount + "/" + room.MaxPlayers).ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMap"].ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMode"].ToString());
                    else
                        cacheRoomUI.Check(room.Name, (room.PlayerCount + "/" + room.MaxPlayers).ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMap"].ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMode"].ToString()
                            , room.CustomProperties["RacingMode"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (room.IsOpen)
                    {
                        CMRoomUI roomUI = Instantiate(roomUIPrefab.gameObject, roomUIParent).GetComponent<CMRoomUI>();
                        roomUIs.Add(roomUI);
                        if (room.CustomProperties["GameMode"].ToString().Equals("CarMeeting"))
                            roomUI.Check(room.Name, (room.PlayerCount + "/" + room.MaxPlayers).ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMap"].ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMode"].ToString());
                        else
                            cacheRoomUI.Check(room.Name, (room.PlayerCount + "/" + room.MaxPlayers).ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMap"].ToString(), room.CustomProperties["GameMode"].ToString()
                              , room.CustomProperties["RaceMode"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (roomUIs.Count > 0) roomFound = true;
        noRoomTextObj.SetActive(!roomFound);
    }
```

After I create a room if another player connects to the looby, I display the cameras visible with those properties, but the property "RaceMode" does not exist.